# Launch activity on click of Overflow Action Menu?

Tags: android, xamarin

What I'm trying to do is launch an activity when the overflow action button is touched which is the three dots in the top right of this image. I don't want to display an overflow menu. Does the menu have a targetable ID that I can use to launch my activity ?

[image: http://cdn.infoq.com/statics_s2_20150807-0037u2/resource/news/2013/06/fries-android-html-javascript/en/resources/fries-1.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your best option is to get an icon of the three dots*, and then instead of dealing with the overflow menu, make a menu item with its icon as the three dots.

You can then wire the button to go to a new activity.

---

*
*Search for `more vert` [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) for Google's three dots icon.*

Comment: Ah alright, I had a feeling that would be my only option but was hoping it wasn't. Cheers!